# Installing iwlwifi drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

[[image]

So basically I am new to ubuntu OS.

I was trying to install the iwlwifi drivers and trying to debug it in c language but I am getting the error as

**make: *** No rule to make target 'defconfig-iwlwifi-public'.  Stop.**

I have run the command  `make defconfig-iwlwifi-public` so can any one please tell me what i can do

[[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome Mohammed. I've edited your question, since it was not readable. You don't need to put screenshots from your terminal - just copy and paste it the next time. Could you please describe (in your question) why you want to compile the drivers. They are already compiled in the repository.

Comment: i want to see how the drivers work, if we compile it by adding the brake points in the program